# WordPress PHP Fatal error: Out of memory - BUT only when listing one of my CPTs in admin

Tags: wordpress, out-of-memory, custom-post-type, custom-fields

We have a WordPress site in which I have create a CPT called Students (along with a few other CPTs), that lists student details for a language school. This data was imported from another site via a csv file and included 4296 student records each with 28 custom fields on top of the standard fields (post_type, post_status, post_date, etc).

I use CMB2 (not the plugin version) to create the 28 custom fields and there are an extra 27 custom fields for extra details that will be used in the future. Most for these fields are simple text, select or radio fields. There are 18 wysiwyg fields but these are not populated yet.

I can view the records in the front-end as a listing and a single entry. I can view a single entry in the back-end too, but when I view the listing page (ie [domain]/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=students) I get the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 250085376) (tried to
>   allocate 71 bytes) in
>   /home/sites/riversdown.com/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line
>   [various line numbers here - but mainly 2204 or 2224]

I started to delete these student entries in bulk and as their numbers reduced the error changed to:

> PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 254541824) (tried to
>   allocate 71 bytes) in
>   /home/sites/riversdown.com/public_html/wp-includes/**meta.php** on
>   line [829 or 826]

by the time I got down to 2709 student records the error went away and I was able to see the listing page in the back-end.

in php.ini I have:

```
max_input_time = 200
max_input_vars = 10000
memory_limit = 512M
```

in wp-config.php I have:

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' );
```

Are there too many posts? To many custom fields? Something else?

Comment: I have since delete all the posts and then imported them back in, in batches of 500, the error appeared at records 2501-3000. I'm now going to delete all records and just import that segment to see if there is an issue with that specific csv file.... nope, the file is fine. Going to try a different combination of the split files to see if it again errors at the 2501-3000 stage.

Comment: Nope, no matter what order I import the data it always errors once I get to the 2501-3000 stage.

Comment: SOLVED. This problem shows up when you use a hierarchical custom post type because WordPress needs to read all posts in order to create the tree-like display of hierarchical posts. Once I changed 'hierarchical' => false, it started working.

Comment: The solution above does not solve the problem if you need to retain the hierarchical structure of post types. The problem is that WordPress caches the meta values of all the posts when listing it. I've written a blog post on how to solve this issue: http://www.junaidbhura.com/wordpress-admin-fix-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-error/